# Does Promise.each in Bluebird has some kind of all operations finished callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am using Bluebird to handle promises but I am having difficulties knowing when all the iterations is finished so I can submit the result back to the client.

So far this is my code:

```
 Student.find({ status: 'student' })
    .populate('student')
    .exec(function (err, students) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        Promise.each(students, function (student) {
            // console.log(student.id);
            return WorksnapsTimeEntry.find({ "student": student.id })
                .then(function (doc) {
                    var totalMinutes = 0;
                    var totalAvgLevelActivity = 0;
                    var counter = 0;
                    _.forEach(doc, function (item) {
                        if (item.timeEntries.duration_in_minutes) {
                            totalMinutes = totalMinutes + parseFloat(item.timeEntries.duration_in_minutes[0]);
                        }

                        if (item.timeEntries.activity_level) {
                            totalAvgLevelActivity = totalAvgLevelActivity + parseFloat(item.timeEntries.activity_level[0]);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    });

                    var obj = {};
                    obj.studentId = student.id;
                    obj.firstName = student.firstName;
                    obj.lastName = student.lastName;
                    obj.municipality = student.municipality;
                    obj.totalMinutes = totalMinutes;
                    obj.totalAvgLevelActivity = totalAvgLevelActivity / counter;
                    arrayReports.push(obj);
                })
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        res.json(arrayReports);
        console.log('finished.');
    }, 5000);
```

As you can see from the code above, I am setting a timeout for 5 seconds till all the above operations are finished and then send the result to the client.

I am looking for something simple and something that my code won't change alot.

Anyone has any idea for this?

Comment: Read my answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819137/foreach-async-function-in-node-js/36819772#36819772 It partially answers this. Promises are chainable using `then()`. In your case, using bluebird's `each` is not necessary and a waste of performance (it processes the input serially instead of doing all requests at the same time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html), Promise.each returns a promise.

```
Promise.each(
    Iterable<any>|Promise<Iterable<any>> input,
    function(any item, int index, int length) iterator
) -> Promise
```

So, I guess you can do this:

```
Promise.each(students, function (student) {
     ....
}).then(function(){
    //all done 
    res.json(arrayReports);
    console.log('finished.');
});
```